# Ubuntu 14.04 Steam font issue

Tags: 14.04, fonts, steam

I had recently installed a fresh copy of trusty and are going to use steam again.
Installation was done easy, steam starts up fine but the result looks like steam is missing some fonts...

[image: http://i.imgur.com/loYhoqX.png]

I thought about missing mscorefont where steam is heavily using it but i installed that before

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.
```

Running steam through a shell env brings up this:

```
steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-03-03 18:36:35] Startup - updater built Feb 18 2015 15:31:44
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
[2015-03-03 18:36:35] Verifying installation...
[2015-03-03 18:36:35] Verification complete
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150218153139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424273499)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150218153139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424305157)
[0303/183635:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
[0303/183636:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0303/183636:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Generating new string page texture 12: 32x256, total string texture memory is 32,77 KB
Generating new string page texture 13: 128x256, total string texture memory is 163,84 KB
Generating new string page texture 14: 256x256, total string texture memory is 425,98 KB
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
```

overlay-scrollbar and unity-gtk-module might not be the reason:

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
overlay-scrollbar is already the newest version.

sudo apt-get install unity-gtk-module-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unity-gtk-module-common is already the newest version.
```

I'm not sure what this exactly means:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
```

Maybe someone can enlighten me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `~/.fonts` folder.

If this folder is empty, please download [SteamFonts](https://support.steampowered.com/downloads/1974-YFKL-4947/SteamFonts.zip) and extract the content of this archive to your `~/.fonts` folder.

After a steam restart the fonts should be back.