# After installing STEAM and launching STEAM, the text is rendered as rectangles, am I missing fonts?

Tags: steam

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 and installed Steam:

EDIT:

Originally, I tried this:

```
apt install steam
```

Then I got this error:

```
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
```

Then ... I looked around to see if perhaps I was installing it from the wrong place, and then did this:

https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb

```
dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

## Apt was complaining about missing some packages ...

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

## run steam

```
steam
```

## output

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 19.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
process 9557: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to stat "/etc/machine-id": Value too large for defined data type
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
process 9557: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to stat "/etc/machine-id": Value too large for defined data type
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Fontconfig warning: line 5: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: line 6: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig warning: line 9: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig error: "conf.d", line 1: failed reading config file
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
process 9557: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to stat "/etc/machine-id": Value too large for defined data type
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize
[0329/211548.041683:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
CApplicationManagerPopulateThread took 0 milliseconds to initialize (will have waited on CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
[0329/211548.061836:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0329/211548.061916:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1585263054
[0329/211548.061921:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0329/211548.061926:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
[0329/211548.112333:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0329/211548.112421:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1585263054
[0329/211548.112426:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0329/211548.112431:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0329/211548.113137:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0329/211548.143220:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(372)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
[0329/211548.179622:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0329/211548.179700:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1585263054
[0329/211548.179704:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0329/211548.179718:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0329/211548.180467:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: utility
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1585264767)

process 9650: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to stat "/etc/machine-id": Value too large for defined data type
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
process 9650: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to stat "/etc/machine-id": Value too large for defined data type
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete
```

Lastly, this is the screen I see:

[image: Steam screenshot]

EDIT:
I have Chinese fonts:

```
locale -a

C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN
zh_CN.gb2312
zh_CN.utf8
```

Both English and Chinese fonts render correctly on my system and English is set as the default.  I'm also using i3 as my window manager if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'll keep that as a comment since it's only a guess: I know that steam is available from the Multiverse official component, without the need to add 3rd party repos. The repo you provided is for ubuntu 12.04 (precise) , and it also claims it is for that old version if you browse to the parent directory [Steam for Linux](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam). Please try installing with apt-get from multiverse, and if this works let us know so I'll convert this to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try - I originally tried installing directly from apt (which I now see shows muiltiverse), but it was complaining about holding broken packages ... see above.

Comment: I followed the instructions here to install steam: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958957/lubuntu-installing-steam-steam-has-no-installation-candidate.  I am still getting the problem, but will try with a fresh install of Ubuntu shortly.

Comment: I tried with a fresh install of Ubuntu / steam and same thing.  Did I follow the right instructions?

Comment: I had a fresh multipurpose 18.04 vm, so I tried installing steam to check the problem as well. Installation was successful [as we can see here](https://imgur.com/a/32cadUz). The fetched package was steam_1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1_i386.deb. Same package also exists at the international repo, and both have the same hash values so they are the same for sure (md5sum after download is: 938a29fbdcaa2cd0ad3c60695567d325). What repo are you using and what packages are downloaded? If it is not the same, try fetching the version I mentioned here.

Comment: Yes, I have the same hash as you listed, and the same version.  I updated my post also indicating that I have both Chinese and English language support, with English being the default.

Comment: I think this actually might be less of ubuntu problem, but more steam app problem. Have you also tried contacting valve? Because if other apps you have parse Chinese fonts correctly, then it must be the app itself.

Comment: I'll contact valve, is your steam directory ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam?  To me, that seems to indicate Ubuntu 12 ... It says updater built on Mar 26 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue in Ubuntu 21.04

First, download the zip from https://support.steampowered.com/downloads/1974-YFKL-4947/SteamFonts.zip

Extract the fonts in that to `~/.local/share/fonts/`

Then

`sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386 cups:i386-`

(the package removal there is to stop it dragging in all kinds of unnecessary stuff)

Then restart Steam.

Proof that it's not anything to do with an "unreleased" version of Ubuntu: [Ubuntu 14.04 Steam font issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592321/ubuntu-14-04-steam-font-issue)

Comment: 21.04 is not released yet. An unreleased version is not an answer.

Comment: I can retry on an older version if you'd like but I can almost certainly guarantee you that this isn't an issue with the newer version. There are reports of this problem back several Ubuntu versions.

Comment: So @David now that 21.04 is released, does that change things?